# Ansible playbook to get all private Ip of my AWS environments

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm running a scan against all the instances on my AWS using Ansible pLaybook  . I need to get their Private IP and list them

I have tried to use json query to filter the Json format. The format output look like this..............

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        { 
            "private_dns_name": "ip-10.89.3.12.ec2.internal", 
            "private_ip_address": "10.89.3.12", 
            "public_dns_name": "", 
            "public_ip_address": null, 

        },
```

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Gather EC2 remote facts.
      ec2_remote_facts:
        region: "{{ region | default('us-east-1') }}"
        filters:
          instance-state-name: running
      register: ec2_remote_facts
    -  set_fact:
         msg: "{{ ec2_remote_facts | json_query('results[*].instances[*].private_ip_address') }} "
    - debug: var=msg
```

I expect the output to be list of private_IP only

Comment: Do you have to use "ec2_remote_facts" only to gather data about EC2? I am asking because this task is now deprecated. You can use "ec2_instance_facts" instead

Answer (score 2):

I tried with "ec2_instance_facts" as below :

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Gather EC2 remote facts.
      ec2_instance_facts:
        filters:
          availability-zone: ap-south-1b
      register: ec2_instance_facts
    -  set_fact:
         msg: "{{ ec2_instance_facts | json_query('instances[*].private_ip_address') }} "
    - debug: var=msg
```

and below is the output :

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Gather EC2 remote facts.] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "172.31.6.87"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Which is correct as per EC2 instance I had created.